# ERROR: column "increment_by" does not exist - Postgres 10 and Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

This seems like a common error with Postgres 10 but I am not sure if its just Postgres 10 or its because I am using Rails 5 as well.  I have a Rails 5 application on Digital Ocean that is getting ready to go live and as I started to implement backups, I ran into a huge issue.  When I try and do backups with Navicat or directly with pg_dump, I am faced with the following error - `[Err] [Bak] Get sequences: ERROR:  column "increment_by" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT last_value, increment_by, max_value, min_value, cache...`

I cannot figure out what to do and there is way too much information already added to the site to tear it down and start over. I am hoping someone here has found a work around, at least to allow me to perform a backup so I can recreate the database in a correct version.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using `increment_by` ?

Comment: Who exactly is complaining about that column? `pg_dump`? `pg_restore`? Something in Rails? There were some changes in the sequence internals between PostgreSQL 9 and 10, AFAIK all the affected things in Rails have fixes out now.

Comment: @Shiko I'm not using `increment_by`

Comment: @muistooshort `pg_dump` is complaining when I try and dump the `DB`.  I even fired up a new Rails app with Postgres 10 and tried to dump the DB and same error happened.  When I reverted back to 9.6, it worked.

Comment: Are you running `pg_dump` yourself? Is the `pg_dump` you're using from PostgreSQL 9 or 10? What version of Rails5 are you using?

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone runs into this with Rails 4.1 (4.1.16 in my case), the answer for Rails 4.2 (here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28780#issuecomment-354868174) works great but I had to make one change to get it to work- I changed `module PostgreSQL` to `class PostgreSQLAdapter`.